# .load not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I've got this code

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
    function carregaPagina($link)
            {
            $( "#destaques" ).load( $link );
            }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var rdoIndex = 0;    
            /* Every 2 seconds, click each radio button */
            var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
            var rdoCount = $('input[name="controls"]').length;
            $('input[name="controls"]:eq(' + rdoIndex%rdoCount + ')').click();
            rdoIndex++;        
            }, 5000);

/* Stops the radio buttons from rolling */
$('#stopBtn').click(function() {
    clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
include('conexaoBD.php');
//ação sobre a tabela
$pergunta="SELECT * FROM noticias LIMIT ".$id.", 2;";
$resposta= mysqli_query($ligaBD, $pergunta);
if (!$resposta)
    {
    echo "<br> Erro: Acesso negado da ação sobre a tabela";
    exit;
    }
// nº de registos devolvidos na ação sobre a tabela
$num_linhas=mysqli_num_rows($resposta);
if (!$num_linhas)
    {
    echo "<br> Erro: Nº de linhas não obtido.";
    exit;
    }
for($i=0; $i<$num_linhas; $i++)
                            {
                            $dados=mysqli_fetch_array($resposta); //leitura de um registo devolvido.
                            $dataOriginal = $dados['data'];
                            $novaData = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dataOriginal));
                            if (!$dados)
                                {
                                echo "<br> Erro: Leitura dos registos devolvidos da ação sobre a BD";
                                exit;
                                }
                            echo "<div class='titulo'>".mb_convert_encoding($dados['titulo'], "utf-8")."</h1></div>";
                            echo "<div class='foto'><img src='Imagens/Noticias/".$dados['foto']."'width='400px' height='200px'></img></div>";
                            echo "<div class='noticia'>".mb_convert_encoding($dados['desc'], "utf-8")."</div>";
                            echo "<div class='datanoticia'>".$novaData."</div>";
                            }
                        echo "<a href='#' onClick='carregaPagina('proximapagina.php?id=".$dados['ID']."');'>Próxima Página</a>";
?>
```

Everything works just fine. My problem is that when I click the link generated by this:

```
  echo "<a href='#' onClick='carregaPagina('proximapagina.php?id=".$dados['ID']."');'>Próxima Página</a>";
```

It doesn't work as intended, which is like it is working on the website, whenever you click a menu item, here: www.cdq.pt

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ?

Comment: When asking `jQuery` questions, it is very useful to provide the output HTML (e.g. as saved from your browser). This saves mentally compiling PHP into something that could be used to mockup the code :)

Comment: You have to checkout the console output of your web browser to know what's exactly the error generated.

Comment: Also what's `$link` in your [tag:javascript] code?

Comment: as SEMSEM said, you need to check your console (F12 in Chrome, go to console) to see your what error you get upon clicking your link.\

Comment: The error I get on my console is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }", on line two of my index, which has "<html>" and no "}" in sight.

Comment: @sємsєм : the $link in my javascript code is the page it will load.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your are sending params so try this:

```
onClick='carregaPaginaWithIdParam('proximapagina.php,".$dados['ID']."');'

///add this function including the id

 function carregaPaginaWithIdParam($link,$ID)
            {
               $( "#destaques" ).load( $link, {'id': $ID} );
            }
```